# Где создать .moc для юнит теста

Tags: c++, qt, юнит-тесты

не видет UnitTests.moc. Где и как его создать?

```
 #include <QString>
 #include <QtTest/QtTest>
 #include "../Category.h"
 #include "../Test.h"
 #include "../Task.h"

class UnitTests : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
     UnitTests();

   private Q_SLOTS:
     void testOne();
};

UnitTests::UnitTests()
{
}

void UnitTests::testOne()
{
    QString stringTest = "Test";
    QCOMPARE(stringTest.toUpper(), QString("Test"));
}

QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(UnitTests)

#include "UnitTests.moc"
```

ошибка:error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'UnitTests.moc': No such file or directory

Comment: Это специальный файл. Его просто так не будет. Скорее всего Вы просто неправильно компилируете.

Comment: его должен создавать `qmake` во время сборки. для большинства систем сборки простым топорным, но гарантированным способом являетсе переконфигурировать проект с нуля... как для vs — я не знаю...

Comment: @Far-Zer у меня qt creator